# How to set Foreground of a TextBlock in a nested grid?

Tags: wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I've a `TextBlock` inside a `Grid` which is inside a `PopupBox` provided by `MaterialDesignInXaml`, a sample structure:

```
xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"

<materialDesign:PopupBox>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Foo" />
    </Grid>
</materialDesign:PopupBox>
```

I'm trying to apply the `TextBlock` foreground as a global resource in my `App.xaml`:

```
 <Style TargetType="materialDesign:PopupBox">
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="red" />
</Style>
```

but not seems to be working, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to define an implicit `Style` for the `Grid`. Try this:

```
<Style TargetType="materialDesign:PopupBox">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```